# How do I save memory when loading images from a URL in a Collection View?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a collection view in my app and want to load images from a url. The collection view is scrollable. If the user scrolls down more images should be paginated from the url.

What should I do with the images that I have loaded so far? One way would be to set the pointer to nil in order to free the space in the heap. But then I have to load then again, when the user scrolls up.

Is there a better way to handle the scrolling and keep the heap memory as low as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use library like `SDWebImage` or `HJCache` which offers asynchronous download and memory and file caching features.

Comment: What is the difference between these libraries?

Comment: `SDWebImage` is more actively maintained and it just does images. `HJCache` is very generic, it does images but can do any type of file. It probably offers more caching and purging options too but I haven't had cause to check `SDWebImage` for that previously.